# Web site blocked by Windows defender and is marked as unsafe in IE

Tags: web-browser

I posted this originally on [Drupal Stack Exchange](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/125093/drupal-site-blocked-by-windows-defender), and it was recommended that I try here for an answer. Here is the original question:

> Visiting my Drupal 7 site just now with IE 11, I get this message:
>
> > Windows Defender blocked content on this website lx7pyv.dofeqilr.com
> >
> > Hosted by: [poligo.com](http://poligo.com) Recommended icon Go to my home page instead
> >     Windows Defender blocked this site because it might contain threats to
> >     your PC or your privacy.
>
> What's up? I get no hits when I search for "lx7pyv.dofeqilr.com". I
>   also have not issues in Chrome or FF. Is my site infected?

Is there some kind of malicious code on my site?

Since posting, I have noticed that it happens sometimes when I switch to Japanese (down in the footer of the site), but the English version seems to be OK. It is also intermittent. The error message changes too. I get different URLs reported, like one.hretiopalika.net.in etc.

Answer (score 1):

Probably has more to do with dofeqilr.com than with your specific subdomain thereof.

http://www.spamhaus.org/query/dbl?domain=dofeqilr.com

Comment: Thanks Joe. I have been looking into it. I have had a Wordpress installation on the same server affected by the Mailpoet attack. It looks like this is the same thing. I have read that it can affect any PHP files on the same server, regardless of whether or not your site has that plugin, or indeed the same CMS.